# I want the images to appear one at a time and stay till the end all images appeared. Then it should play in a loop

Tags: css

I want to stop 1st image when it appears in its place, then the 2nd to slide from where the 1st image has stopped to appear and then 3rd and so on. I want to use HTML and CSS only. But the images are not stopping, don't know where i am going wrong. I want this to play in a loop.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#">
<style>
#wrapper{
width: 300px;
height: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #E6E7E8;
}

#banner{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
animation-name: shift;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shift{
0%{ background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
25%{ background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
transform: translateY(100px);}
50%{ background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/150);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
transform: translateY(200px);}
75%{ background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/100);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
transform: translateY(300px);}
100%{ background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
transform: translateY(400px);}
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="banner">
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try stacking the images

Comment: I'm afraid You can't do that with a single div using background image. Use img tag.

Comment: Hey Newton, i tried with img tag but the problem with that is after 1st image appears it starts looping and then the 2nd appears then both goes in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this. I don't know if there are any better ways but this works with the help of script.

```
<style>
  #wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #E6E7E8;
  }

  #banner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
  }

  img {
    display: none;
  }

</style>
 </head>

 <body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="banner">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
var x = 0;  
window.setInterval(function(){
$("#banner").children("img").eq(x).fadeIn(400);
if(x<4){x++;}
else{x=0;$("#banner").children("img").css("display","none") }
}, 1000);
```

Hope this helps

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7a6ofvt/)

Comment: Hey thanks. It works fine with script. But the site where i am going to upload the banner rejects if the theres any js involve. Its only HTML and internal CSS.